# Filename with added modified date and assign it to a variable

Tags: linux, filenames

I want to find a file in a Unix directory and if exist I want to assign the filename along with its modified time stamp to a variable like the below

```
variable=(find the file name, if exist add the filename with _a string _and modified time stamp)
```

Is it possible? It should look like `filename_string_modifieddate(yyyymmdd)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
variable=`find . putYourConditionHere -exec ls -l --time-style +(%Y%m%d): {} \;|sed 's/.*\(([0-9]*)\): \(.*\)/\2_string_modifieddate\1/'`
```

So you use `find` to find your file, use option `-exec` exec `ls` on it with option `--time-style` to get the desired format and finally `sed` to get the correct order. Pass this to your variable.

I included the `:` in the date because a file name must not contain it. Otherwise the script would fail for filenames including something like `()` or `(42)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var=$(find -name yourfile -prune -printf '%f_%TY%Tm%Td\n')
```

This will stuff shell variable `var` with `yourfile_yyyymmdd` `iff` yourfile exists.

In case your `find` doesn't understand the above `printf primitives` you could do this in following manner:

```
var=$(find -name yourfile -prune -exec sh -c 'printf "%s_%s\n" "$1" "$(stat -c "%y" "$1" | cut -d " "-f1 | tr -d "-")"' {} {} \;)
```

Comment: will it work in aix flavour i am getting badoption for printf

Comment: @user2310119: Well I don't have `AIX` but if this doesn't work there, then you could do this: `var="yourfile_$(stat -c '%y' yourfile | cut -d ' ' -f1 | tr -d '-')"`